# Implementing long polling with retrofit and kotlin channels

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, polling, long-polling

I am trying to implement long polling which is lifecycle aware(in Activity/Fragment). The polling will be scoped to the fragment which sends API request to the server every fixed interval of time. However, I am unable to implement it.

#### This is how I want the implementation to be like

> - Have a *hard timeout* on client-side without considering any extra delay incurred in receiving the response.
> - *Wait for the response of previous API call* before sending the next request.  i.e., the request in polling queue should wait for response irrespective of its priority due to polling interval

Consider:

HARD_TIMEOUT = 10s

POLLING_INTERVAL = 2s
[image]

```
 Request 1: Started at: 0sec      Response delay:1.2sec   Duration left: 0.8sec
 Request 2: Started at: 2sec      Response delay:0.4sec   Duration left: 1.6sec
 Request 3: Started at: 4sec      Response delay:2.5sec   Duration left: 0sec
 Request 4: Started at: 6.5sec    Response delay:0.5sec   Duration left: 1.0sec
 Request 5: Started at: 8sec      Response delay:0.8sec   Duration left: 1.2sec
```

For this use case, I want to use polling instead of socket. Any Idea/solutions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can use [ticker](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/ticker.html), for example https://pl.kotl.in/mP5Rl4k0K

Comment: @IR42 ticker is annotated with ObsoleteCoroutinesApi, can't use it in production, a redesign of could possibly crash or make the app behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Figured out a solution for polling using channels. this should help someone searching for an example.

```
    private val pollingChannel = Channel<Deferred<Result<OrderStatus>>>()
    val POLLING_TIMEOUT_DURATION = 10000L
    val POLLING_FREQUENCY = 2000L
```

> A channel is required to hold your asynchronous request just in case more request comes in while your async task is being executed.

```
    val pollingChannel = Channel<Deferred<Pair<Int,Int>>>()
```

> **QUEUE EXECUTOR**: It will pick an async task and start executing them in FIFO order.

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        for (i in pollingChannel) {
            val x = i.await()
            println("${SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().time)} Request ${x.first}: value ${x.second}")
        }
    }
```

> **POLLING FUNCTION**: Adds your async task to the polling channel every fixed interval of time until timeout.

```
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        var reqIndex = 1
        val timedOut = withTimeoutOrNull(POLLING_TIMEOUT_DURATION) {
            while (receiverJob.isActive) {
                pollingChannel.send(async {
                    getRandomNumber(reqIndex++)
                })
                delay(POLLING_FREQUENCY)
            }
        }
    }
```

> **ASYNCHRONOUS OPERATION**

to avoid answer being verbose I created a function with a random delay, please replace with the required API call

```
   private suspend fun getRandomNumber(index: Int): Pair<Int,Int> {
    val randomDuration = (1..6L).random() * 500
    delay(randomDuration)
    return Pair(index,(0..100).random())
}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

[image]